# How to read a listview Item (Label) in JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to read an Item values in JQuery, Based on the value I want to enable or disable an Anchor tag in the Listview based on the label value. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#Coverage-link').live('click', function(e) {
                    var IsRestriction = ***I want to read a label text(lblRestrictions) here***
                    if (IsRestriction == "More") {
                        $('#Coverage-form').dialog('open');
                    } else {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                    return false;
                });
});
```

Listview Item -

```
 <ItemTemplate>
                <tr >
                    <td align="left" style="width:180px">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDrugName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DrugDescription") %>' /> 
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:120px" align="center">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FormularyStatusDescription") %>' /> 
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" style="width:250px">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFlat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CopayInfo") %>' /> 
                    </td>       
                    <td style="width:80px;padding-right:10px;" align="center">
                        <!--<asp:Label ID="lblCoverageRestrictions" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Restrictions") %>' /> -->
                        <a href="#" id="Coverage-link">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRestrictions" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Restrictions") %>' ></asp:Label> 
                        </a>
                    </td>   
                </tr>
             </ItemTemplate>
```

Here is the HTML output -

```
<table id="eligibility-data">
                    <thead style="background-color:#90a595;">
                        <th style="width:180px">Drug Name</th>
                        <th style="width:120px;">Formulary Status</th>
                        <th align="left" style="width:250px">Copay Information</th>
                        <th style="width:80px;padding-right:10px">Restrictions</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                <tr >
                    <td align="left" style="width:180px">
                        <span id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_formularyControl_lvCopayInformation_ctrl0_lblDrugName">ibuprofen 200 mg oral capsule</span> 
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:120px" align="center">
                        <span id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_formularyControl_lvCopayInformation_ctrl0_lblStatus">On - Preferred (2)</span> 
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" style="width:250px">
                        <span id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_formularyControl_lvCopayInformation_ctrl0_lblFlat">No Copay Info Available.</span> 
                    </td>       
                    <td id="tdRestrictions" style="width:80px;padding-right:10px;" align="center">
                        <!--<span id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_formularyControl_lvCopayInformation_ctrl0_lblCoverageRestrictions">None</span> -->
                        <a href="#" id="Coverage-link">
                        <span id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_formularyControl_lvCopayInformation_ctrl0_lblRestrictions">None</span> 
                        </a>
                    </td>   
                </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: Can you share the final HTML output, instead of the ASP server-side code?

Comment: Please find the HTML code added.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that the  directive  outputs a html  tag with the contents inside.

Then, to retrieve the label text you could use:

```
var IsRestriction = $('#Coverage-link label').text()
```

The IsRestriction variable should then have the string of the asp:Label directive

Comment: Thank you eltuza.    The ASP:Label has simple text "None" or "More" based on this I want to open a form using JQuery. I have added the HTML output of the listview, please refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx) on the server side?

```
 protected void ContactsListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
 {
    //Label EmailAddressLabel;
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        //PUT YOUR LOGIC HERE

        // Display the e-mail address in italics.
        //EmailAddressLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("EmailAddressLabel");
        //EmailAddressLabel.Font.Italic = true;

        //System.Data.DataRowView rowView = e.Item.DataItem as System.Data.DataRowView;
        //string currentEmailAddress = rowView["EmailAddress"].ToString();
        //if (currentEmailAddress == "orlando0@adventure-works.com")
        //{
        //EmailAddressLabel.Font.Bold = true;
        //}
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Rick. I find myself in the same boat that Senthil is in. I can see by his code above that he is trying to display the data in a CSS style DIV box, which is client side, so is accessed via jquery. I have not yet found a way to do this.